# How to stub/mock multiple options depending on user input with Rspec 3.4

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, rspec3

I am completely new to Rspec, and it's my first time trying to test outside of the rails framework. I am simply trying to understand how I can possibly mock behavior of my app when the implementation is pretty complex.

I want to be able to mimic the behavior of calling `customize_gender` inputting a choice and checking that when 1 is entered the result is 'Male', when 2 is entered the result is 'Female', etc.

I also want to be able to check if the instance variable of `@gender` was correctly set, which is why I added the `attr_reader :gender` in the first place. I have been trying a few things, but I guess I do not understand how mocks in general work to be able to find a solution. I have looked at similar questions but they do not seem to work for my scenario. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Main file (person.rb)

```
 class Person
  attr_reader :gender

  GENDER = { male: 'Male', female: 'Female', other: 'Other'}

  def initialize
    puts customize_gender
  end

  def customize_gender
    display_hash_option GENDER, 'What is your gender? '
    choice = gets.chomp.to_i
    @gender =
      case choice
      when 1
        GENDER[:male]
      when 2
        GENDER[:female]
      when 3
        print 'Enter your preferred gender: '
        gets.chomp.downcase
      else
        puts 'Error: Person -> customize_gender()'
      end
  end

  private

  def display_hash_option(hash, saying = '')
    print saying
    hash.each_with_index { |(key, _value), index| print "#{index.next}) #{key} " }
  end

end
```

Rspec File (spec/person_spec.rb)

```
require_relative "../person"
describe Person do
    let(:person) { Person.new }
    allow(Person).to receive(:gets).and_return(1,2,3)
    person.customize_gender
    expect(person.gender).to eq 'Male'
    # allow(person).to receive(:customize_gender).and_return('Male')
    # expect(Person).to receive(:puts).with('What is your gender?')
    # allow(Person).to receive(:gets) { 1 }
    # expect(person.gender).to eq 'Male'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it, the only thing mocked here is that `gets` is set to '1' (remember it's a string in this case as `gets` input is always a string)

```
RSpec.describe Person do
  subject { Person.new }

  it 'returns male as gender when male is chosen' do
    allow(subject).to receive(:gets).and_return('1')
    subject.customize_gender

    expect(subject.gender).to eq('Male')
  end
end
```

For `when 3` you could use the following.

```
RSpec.describe Person do
  subject { Person.new }

  it 'returns other as gender when other has been entered' do
    allow(subject).to receive(:gets).and_return('3', 'other')
    subject.customize_gender

    expect(subject.gender).to eq('other')
  end
end
```

Comment: That works for simple cases, but what about the nested gets inside the `when 3` clause? Is there a way to simulate that? I am just trying to figure out a way to accommodate all edge cases elegantly.

Comment: What I mean is yeah it should work for the first case when the user enters `3`. But if the user enters 3 then right away he is asked to input another gender of his choice. so for example the flow will be as follows: `enter 3 -> enter 'other' -> result should be 'other'`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. I will mark it as solved, but quick question. Is there any difference between that and `allow(subject).to receive(:gets).exactly(2).times.and_return('3', 'Other')` ?

Comment: You would use ``.exactly(2).times.and_return`` with ``expect`` (to ensure it does not get called more than that for example). Try using ``expect(subject).to receive(:gets).exactly(3).times.and_return('3', 'Other')`` instead and watch the outcome.

Comment: Yes, I got that from the name haha. I just wanted to make sure. Thanks for all the help! :D